# WARNING: Device for xxx not found or rejected by a filter

Tags: lvm

Seem to be having some disk corruptions issues, and not sure the best way to proceed.  I have a very large disk used for video storage that is made up lvms.  (sda) I unmounted it and now can't remount it (now for obvious reasons)

```
root@hartserver:/home/paulh# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0   4.6T  0 disk
└─sda1                        8:1    0   4.6T  0 part
  ├─extra--space-vmdisk     253:2    0  10.1T  0 lvm
  └─extra--space-playground 253:3    0   300G  0 lvm
sdb                           8:16   0 232.4G  0 disk
├─sdb1                        8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2                        8:18   0 231.9G  0 part
  ├─hartserver--vg-root     253:0    0 753.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─hartserver--vg-swap_1   253:1    0    48G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdd                           8:48   0   931G  0 disk
└─sdd1                        8:49   0   931G  0 part
  └─hartserver--vg-root     253:0    0 753.6G  0 lvm  /
sde                           8:64   0   4.6T  0 disk
└─extra--space-vmdisk       253:2    0  10.1T  0 lvm
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

It appears that one of the pv is now "unknown"

```
# pvs
  /dev/extra-space/vmdisk: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 11050237755392: Input/output error
  /dev/extra-space/vmdisk: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 11050237812736: Input/output error
  WARNING: Device for PV FeGB9a-1FJN-ljSk-yH0r-R0tc-i8ja-Ck0VxF not found or rejected by a filter.
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda1  extra-space   lvm2 a--    <4.55t      0
  /dev/sdb2  hartserver-vg lvm2 a--   231.87g      0
  /dev/sdd1  hartserver-vg lvm2 a--  <931.00g 361.30g
  /dev/sde   extra-space   lvm2 a--    <4.55t      0
  [unknown]  extra-space   lvm2 a-m    <4.55t   3.30t
```

I am not a disk expert, but it would appear that my /dev/sde1? is gone?

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you seem to be using the entire `sde` disk for LVM, and it seems to be working normally, it would be impossible to have `sde1`. Whatever the missing disk is, it would seem to be the latest addition to the `extra-space` volume group, as it seems to have been only partially allocated unlike the other components of the VG.